# General Purpose Testing Framework written in Golang

Tags: automated-testing, testing-framework

By ***`general purpose testing framework`*** it means something like a [PyTest](http://pythontesting.net/). **PyTest** is written in Python but the framework can be used as a general framework tool to test different kinds of systems those have nothing to do with Python.

How would you create/design such a framework in golang? Has such a framework written in golang already exist that can serve as a starting point or reference?

While searching online it finds mainly two classes of testing frameworks with golang:

1. That is used to test systems written in golang too.
2. That is to test network related processes.

I'm looking for something that can be used to test just anything like the PyTest can. As an extreme example, it'd be the best if it can be used to drive testing of an embedded-system.

Answer (score 3):

When you set out to solve as general a problem as "something that can be used to test just anything", the programming language you use to code the framework is less important than the abstractions you support.  That is where I would start.